# How to replace an existing DialogFlow action with Assistant SDK action

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, actions-builder

We have an existing Dialogflow Google action in production today. We would like to replace it with a new Google Assistant SDK action with the same invocation name. When I created a new SDK project, I was not allowed to use the existing invocation name, so I had to use a temporary invocation name, how do I deploy it for review with the production invocation name? What is the process of replacing it?

Answer (score 0):

A migration tool was launched by the team.

This will help make it easier for you. The announcement is shared on [Twitter](http://twitter.com/ActionsOnGoogle/status/1303730732804780033?s=20) .

But here're the relevant documentation that will help.

- [Overview] -> [goo.gle/3bHkAzz](http://goo.gle/3bHkAzz)
- [Project migration] -> [goo.gle/3mggzqW](http://goo.gle/3mggzqW)
- [Fulfillment migration] -> [goo.gle/2Rb1mZK](http://goo.gle/2Rb1mZK)